# When publishing a structure group, the pages inside it aren't published

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am facing an issue when publishing Structure groups in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

The published files are configured to be stored at **"E:\TridionContent\content"**.

When I publish the entire structure group, its status in the Publishing queue is **Success** but the content is not actualt published to at the location specified above. I am surprised to observe the status in Publishing queue always immediately shows **Success**.

Publishing the page individually or a group of pages is successfull.

Every time I had to open the structure group to publish the pages separately.

I Wonder if I need to change some configuration to publish Structure groups as well.

I checked cd_storage_conf.xml, there I find the following entries under `<ItemTypes>` .

```
<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" cached="false"/>
```

I am not sure If I need to add one more Item with the typemapping as StructureGroup.

Can some one tell me how to fix this issue so that I can publish entire structure group in one go?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be one of two things:

1> The Structure Group is marked as unpublishable, as is detailed in this question

[Why does publishing a page in a non-publishable structure group give a publishing success status?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/143/why-does-publishing-a-page-in-a-non-publishable-structure-group-give-a-publishin)

2> The pages in the Structure Group have not yet been published to the target you are using.

In the case of two you can uncheck the checkbox in the publish dialog that says

'Republish only (Do not publish new content)'

In the case of one, if you right click a Structure Group, and select 'Properties' you will see a 'Publishable' checkbox.

Comment: In addition to above steps you can Check the properties of the structure group whether in it's properties is it marked publishable.(Publishable checkbox)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just found that I am publishing the pages in the structure group for the first time. So option 2 is applicable to me. I have tried unchecking the option Republish only. Now its fine. I could publish

Answer (score 7):

When troubleshooting publishing please select the 'See items to Publish' button on the publish dialog to see what items Tridion plans to publish.  My guess is that list is empty for your Structure Group.  One reason might be that the Pages inside the Structure Group have never been published to that target.  This is the default functionality and pages must be published manually the first time.

Tridion will say 'success' even if the 'See items to Publish' window contains 0 items.  And, yes, the very quick success message is a sign something is not quite working...

Tridion 2011 has the 'Republish only' option on the Publish Settings tab and it is true by default.  Try unchecking this option and then select 'See Items to Publish' again.

Your cd_storage file looks fine and should not impact this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unchecking the Republish option worked